# Seasonal ARIMA lag differencing p-value not significant

Tags: r, arima, data-transformation, model-selection

I am using the below data to forecast using seasonal ARIMA model. I see at `d=1` the p-value is not significant. But still `auto.arima` model suggests `d=1`. I am not sure if I should use the first differencing. Any help is much appreciated.

```
dput(Enrollment_Data)
structure(list(Enrolled_COUNT = c(17L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 45L, 21L, 
18L, 43L, 82L, 116L, 192L, 289L, 242L, 254L, 335L, 138L, 71L, 
98L, 91L, 138L, 175L, 232L, 155L, 376L, 197L, 271L, 421L, 112L, 
140L), Enrolment_date = structure(c(27L, 22L, 5L, 11L, 8L, 18L, 
1L, 20L, 16L, 14L, 3L, 28L, 25L, 23L, 6L, 12L, 9L, 19L, 2L, 21L, 
17L, 15L, 4L, 29L, 26L, 24L, 7L, 13L, 10L), .Label = c("Apr-18", 
"Apr-19", "Aug-18", "Aug-19", "Dec-17", "Dec-18", "Dec-19", "Feb-18", 
"Feb-19", "Feb-20", "Jan-18", "Jan-19", "Jan-20", "Jul-18", "Jul-19", 
"Jun-18", "Jun-19", "Mar-18", "Mar-19", "May-18", "May-19", "Nov-17", 
"Nov-18", "Nov-19", "Oct-18", "Oct-19", "Sep-17", "Sep-18", "Sep-19"
), class = "factor"), t = structure(c(23L, 5L, 11L, 8L, 18L, 
1L, 21L, 16L, 14L, 3L, 28L, 26L, 24L, 6L, 12L, 9L, 19L, 2L, 22L, 
17L, 15L, 4L, 29L, 27L, 25L, 7L, 13L, 10L, 20L), .Label = c("Apr-18", 
"Apr-19", "Aug-18", "Aug-19", "Dec-17", "Dec-18", "Dec-19", "Feb-18", 
"Feb-19", "Feb-20", "Jan-18", "Jan-19", "Jan-20", "Jul-18", "Jul-19", 
"Jun-18", "Jun-19", "Mar-18", "Mar-19", "Mar-20", "May-18", "May-19", 
"Nov-17", "Nov-18", "Nov-19", "Oct-18", "Oct-19", "Sep-18", "Sep-19"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-29L))
```

**Code:**

```
d.COUNT <- diff(Enrolled_COUNT, differences = 1)
adf.test(d.COUNT, alternative="stationary")

Enrolled_COUNT2 <- ts(Enrollment_Data[,'Enrolled_COUNT'], frequency = 12)
auto.arima(Enrolled_COUNT2, stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE, seasonal = TRUE)

arima.final
```

**Results:**

````
Series: Enrolled_COUNT2 
ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,0)[12] 

Coefficients:
          ma1
      -0.4856
s.e.   0.2201

sigma^2 estimated as 7796:  log likelihood=-94.01
AIC=192.02   AICc=192.95   BIC=193.57

```
````

Comment: What $p$-value is not significant? What does *lad* mean in your title? Consider formulating your question more carefully.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo error. I meant by lag value. And p-values is greater than 0.05 for my model.

Comment: This still does not answer the question of what $p$-value this is. What test does it correspond to?

Comment: Ah ok sorry I understood now, I performed the dickey-fuller test on the variable Enrolled_COUNT. The p-value for this variable is above 0.05. Below is the result ```Dickey-Fuller = -1.9059, Lag order = 3, p-value = 0.6085
alternative hypothesis: stationary ```